# pattern read, match, replace from two files and create output file with the results

Tags: linux

I would like to know how to use replace for this scenario. I have 2 files called **myfile.txt** & **responsefile.txt** as below.

**myfile.txt**

```
user=myname
user_1=yourname
group=mygroup
group_1=yourgroup
```

**responsefile.txt**

```
#Please fill the user id details.
user=
#user_1=    

#Please fill the group id details.
group=
#group_1=
```

Now, using above two files want to have the following end result after replacing the matching patterns. The responsefile.txt content should be intact just the matched pattern should be prefixed with details provided in myfile.txt or only replace the whole matching line as pattern are same in both the files.

**responsefile.txt (new file replaced/substituted with patterns)**

```
#Please fill the user id details.
user=myname
user_1=yourname    
#Please fill the group id details.
group=mygroup
group_1=yourgroup
```

Patterns would be without hash or with hash so have to remove hash on match. Please note the file responsefile.txt is lenghty of about 604L, 16481C

Please suggest, would like to have simple solution as the content in actual scenario will have more than 100 similar patterns. Above one is just for example.

Thanks
Raajesh

Comment: Have you tried merge? I din't try it, but it may help http://linux.die.net/man/1/merge I think you would have to install rcs package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This awk should work:

```
awk -F '=' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} !($1 in a){print} ($1 in a){print $0 a[$1]}' myfile.txt responsefile.txt
```

**Expanded form:**

```
awk -F '=' 'FNR == NR {
   a[$1] = $2;
   next
}
!($1 in a) {
   print
}
($1 in a) {
   print $0 a[$1]
}' myfile.txt responsefile.txt
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
'#'Please fill the user id details.
'#'Here is example user=urname.
user==myname

'#'Please fill the group id details.
'#'Here is example group=urgroup.
group==mygroup
```

Comment: Anubhava, i updated the awk provided by you to ignore double "=". its working good thanks again for u help.

Comment: Oh that's right, There already was a trailing `=`. Glad that it worked out for you.

Comment: Actually it is difficult to read data from comment. Edit your question and provide this input file and expected output. I can then suggest my solution.

Comment: So you just want to ignore lines that start with # OR want some other changes also?

Comment: hi if u observe for example    user_1=     is hashed in responsefile when not processed, but when processed it is updated as    user_1=yourname.

Comment: So you want script to find and remove hash also in 2nd file?

Comment: @user2692634: Thought it was minor change but it is turning out to be more than that. Request you to create a new question linking this one and leave me a comment here with the new question's link.

Comment: i see u are in superuser, i had posted new request yesterday based on ur code    [link](http://superuser.com/questions/675403/match-patterns-update-output-file-uncomment-when-desired/675450?noredirect=1#675450)

Comment: @user2692634: This is actually a programming question so more suited on SO. If you create a new question on SO here I will sure attend it.